# Xamarin UI Tests IOS Device Error: Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : Failed to install DeviceAgent

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin, device

Configuration:

Visual Studio 8.5 Build 2739
Mono 6.8.0.104
Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

Visual Studio 8.4.5 Build 19
Mono 6.6.0.155
Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

Code:

```
ConfigureApp.iOS
            .InstalledApp("com.xamarin.MyNewApp55")
            .StartApp();
```

Exception:

> Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : Failed to install
>   DeviceAgent
>
> ExitCode: 5
>
> ```
>   -c,--codesign-identity  <codesign-identifier> [OPTIONAL]    Identity
> ```
>
> used to codesign app bundle [device only]. Deprecated - should use
>   profile path. DEFAULT=        -d,--device-id   iOS
>   Simulator GUID, physical device ID, or an alias
>         -f,--force   [OPTIONAL]    Reinstall the app if
>   the device contains an older version than the bundle
>   specified DEFAULT=0       -i,--resources-path  [OPTIONAL]
>     Path to resources (executables) to inject into app directory. A list
>   of colon separated files may be specified.
>         -p,--profile-path    [OPTIONAL]   Path to provisioning
>   profile   install  Application
>   com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner is not installed on
>   00008030-0003048114F0802E Error installing application: Failed to
>   install application with path
>   /var/folders/39/0rfg9kc92gx9bbslgw3td95h0000gq/T/xdb/DeviceAgent.iOS.Dependencies/b747d1445588083eee4d1d93a53f3e5b/ipa/DeviceAgent-Runner.app

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi ,  welcome to SO ! You can have a try with `.AppBundle("path")` to have a try start UITest .

Answer (score 1):

**About** method ***[InstalledApp(string bundleId)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.configuration.iosappconfigurator.installedapp?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk#Xamarin_UITest_Configuration_iOSAppConfigurator_InstalledApp_System_String_)*** , it has follow definition :

> Configures the installed app to use. Will force a run on physical device.

[image]

You should run it in a physical device .

**Therefore** , if need to run in simulator device ,should use ***[AppBundle (string path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.configuration.iosappconfigurator.appbundle?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk#Xamarin_UITest_Configuration_iOSAppConfigurator_AppBundle_System_String_)*** :

> Configures the app bundle to use. Will force a run on simulator.

[image]

The `AppBundle` method can be used to specify where on the file system the app bundle may be found. There are two ways to do so, with an absolute path, or a relative path. This snippet shows using an absolute path to the app bundle:

```
IApp app = ConfigureApp
    .iOS
    .AppBundle("/path/to/iosapp.app")
    .StartApp();
```

To use a relative path, the path must be relative to the Xamarin.UITest assembly. This snippet is and example of how to use a relative path to locate the app bundle:

```
IApp app = ConfigureApp
    .iOS
    .AppBundle("../../../iOSAppProject/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/iosapp.app")
    .StartApp();
```

The relative path example tells `AppBundle` to go up three directories from the Xamarin.UITest assembly, and then navigate down the project tree of the iOS application project to find the app bundle.

Here is the official document about ***[Initialize IApp for iOS Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/#initialize-iapp-for-ios-applications)***.